# A question on binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How you do apply the binomial theorem to deduce that $(\frac34)^{\frac45}=0.7944$ correct to $4$dp?

I've written $(\frac34)^{\frac45}=((1-\frac14)^5)^{\frac14}$ then expanded the RHS to get 
$(1-\binom{5}{1}(\frac14)+\binom{5}{2}(\frac14)^2-\binom{5}{3}(\frac14)^3+\binom{5}{4}(\frac14)^4-(\frac14)^5)^{\frac14}$ But I don't know how to go further or if I'm even doing this right

Comment: you seem to have confused $\frac45$ and $\frac54$; anyway, $(1-\frac14)^{4/5}=1-\frac45\frac14+\frac12\frac45\frac{-1}5(\frac14)^2+\cdots$

Comment: Also for fractional or negative exponents, use Newton's generalised Binomial Theorem. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem